# How do you call a method which uses two objects and an input from the main class?

Tags: object, methods, parameters, arguments

I am trying to create a program in Java that simulates the operation of two vending machines within a break room but am experiencing errors with my method when calling it. I am trying to call the method with only one call. I have provided a link to my program below. Please ignore the class called Main as I am using the class called BreakRoom to call my method.

(https://www.online-java.com/4DINZBUcAH)

I also tried calling the method with the two objects shown in the BreakRoom class and that did not seem to work either.